# How to spy on a fakerjs method call

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, faker.js

[Faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) allow you to easily create faked data using for example the following:

```js
import * as faker from 'faker'
console.log(faker.lorem.text())
```

So I tried to mock this library to spy the use of `faker.lorem.text()`:

```js
import * as faker from 'faker'

const mockFakerLoremText = jest.fn()
jest.mock('faker', () => ({
  lorem: {
    text: mockFakerLoremText
  }
}))


it('should have called lorem.text() method', () => {
  faker.lorem.text()

  expect(mockFakerLoremText).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

But then I got the following error:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockFakerLoremText' before initialization

So has someone an idea how I can spy on the call of this method `.lorem.text()`?

Comment: Are you testing some production code that *uses* faker, or using faker to generate data for testing?

Comment: Yes I want to use production code that use this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs [Calling jest.mock() with the module factory parameter](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter)

> A limitation with the factory parameter is that, since calls to `jest.mock()` are hoisted to the top of the file, it's not possible to first define a variable and then use it in the factory

That's why you got the error.

An working example using `"jest": "^26.6.3"`:

`index.test.js`:

```js
import * as faker from 'faker';

jest.mock('faker', () => ({
  lorem: {
    text: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

it('should have called lorem.text() method', () => {
  faker.lorem.text();

  expect(faker.lorem.text).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65924623/index.test.ts
  √ should have called lorem.text() method (3 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.913 s, estimated 7 s
```

Comment: Perfect thanks for this solution. But since I use the value of `faker.lorem.text()` after the test I got a runtime error because the return value is `undefined` due to `jest.fn()`. I fixed it by using `jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'fakedText' )`.